# React-native bottomtab navigation icons not showing

Tags: react-native, bottomnavigationview, bottomtabs

This is my App.js. I'm trying to add bottom tabs for my app.

`

```
import React from 'react';
import { View, Text, StyleSheet } from 'react-native';
import Home from './components/Home';
import Details from './components/Details';
import Liked from './components/Liked';
import Profile from './components/Profile';
import colors from './assets/colors/colors';
import Entypo from 'react-native-vector-icons/Entypo';


import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native';
import { createStackNavigator } from '@react-navigation/stack';
import { createBottomTabNavigator } from '@react-navigation/bottom-tabs';

Entypo.loadFont();



const Stack = createStackNavigator();
const Tab = createBottomTabNavigator();

const TabNavigator = () => {
  return (
    <Tab.Navigator
      screenOptions={{
        headerShown: false,
        tabBarStyle: styles.tabBar,
        tabBarActiveTintColor: colors.orange,
        tabBarInactiveTintColor: colors.gray,
      }}>

      <Tab.Screen name="Home" component={Home}
        options={{
          tabBarIcon: ({ size, color }) =>
            <Entypo name="home" size={size} color={color} />,
        }} />

      <Tab.Screen name="Liked" component={Liked} options={{
        tabBarIcon: ({ size, color }) =>
          <Entypo name="home" size={size} color={color} />,
      }} />

      <Tab.Screen name="Profile" component={Profile} options={{
        tabBarIcon: ({ size, color }) =>
          <Entypo name="home" size={size} color={color} />,
      }} />

    </Tab.Navigator>
  )
}

const App = () => {
  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
      <Stack.Navigator>
        <Stack.Screen name="TabNavigator" component={TabNavigator} />
      </Stack.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  tabBar: {
    position: 'absolute',
    backgroundColor: colors.white,
    borderTopLeftRadius: 20,
    borderTopRightRadius: 20,
  },
})

export default App;
```

`

This is my dependencies
`

```
"dependencies": {
    "@react-native-masked-view/masked-view": "^0.2.8",
    "@react-navigation/bottom-tabs": "^6.4.0",
    "@react-navigation/native": "^6.0.13",
    "@react-navigation/stack": "^6.3.4",
    "react": "18.1.0",
    "react-native": "0.70.4",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "^2.8.0",
    "react-native-ionicons": "^4.6.5",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "^4.4.1",
    "react-native-screens": "^3.18.2",
    "react-native-vector-icons": "^9.2.0"
  },
```

`

This is android build

[image: Bottom tab icons are not showing]

What can I do?

I want to get showed bottom tab icons. I tried other icon packages as well. (eg: feather, MaterialCommunityIcons and Ionicons). I think icon pack works fine. What can I do for this?

Comment: Have you completed the installation steps? https://github.com/oblador/react-native-vector-icons#option-with-gradle-recommended

Answer (score 0):

```
tabBarIcon: ({ focused, color, size }) => {
        let iconName;
        iconName = focused ? 'calendar-alt' : 'calendar-alt';


        return <Icon name={iconName} size={size} color={color} />;
      },
```

maybe focused Arg takes diffrent values
some packages in react-vector-icons not working,try with another icon packages,or change the name with test name like  name="menu"

Answer (score 0):

I think either you have missed installation steps of vector icons or you did not mention `Entypo` in `android/app/build.gradle` file.

```
project.ext.vectoricons = [
    iconFontNames: [ 'MaterialIcons.ttf', 'EvilIcons.ttf' ] // Name of the font files you want to copy
]
```

You need to mention `Entypo.ttf` here.